Relation between harmonic and analytic functions
Assume that $f(z)$ and $f^2(z)$ are complex harmonic functions on a domain $D\subset \mathbb{C}$, is that true that either $f$ or $\bar{f}$ is analytic on $D$?
Using the fact that $\Delta=4\partial\bar{\partial}$, it follows that
$$
\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{z}}\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\bar{z}}}=0
$$
this shows that, locally, $f$ or $\bar{f}$ is analytic, but how can one prove that either $f$ or $\bar{f}$ is analytic on $D$?

Write $f=g+\bar h$ where $g,h$ analytic (locally if $D$ is not simply connected) and then $f^2$ harmonic means $g\bar h$ must be harmonic; from here it follows that either $g$ or $h$ are constant by connectedness (if the representation is only local a standard extra connectedness argument considering the set of $w$ where $g_w$ constant vs the one where $h_w$ constant is needed)

@Conrad, thanks for the reply. Why $g$ or $h$ are constant?

Because for example the laplacian is easily seen to be a multiple of $g'\overline{h'}$ so that being zero means at least one the factors is zero on an uncountable set so has a zero accumulation point so is zero on all domain; or you can look at the power series expansion at a point $w$ (which is in terms of $z-w,\overline{z-w}$) and note that harmonic means that you do not have mixed terms, just powers of $z-w$ and $\overline{z-w}$ separate and that is easily seen by induction to imply that one of the expansions is constant)
